# FFmpeg Some Questions about dshow command

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow

Recently, I've built ffmpeg(ver 4.1.1) 32bit on my Windows, trying to put SRT stream to Internet.When I use -dshow command, I can use both -list_device and -list_options to find my camera correctly.But once I use ffplay to play my Camera，it doesn't respond.
On the other hand, I can use vfwcap command to play my Camera successfully through "ffplay -f vfwcap -i 0",but this is not what I want. Because I also want to put my Microphone device at the same time.
[image]
This problem has bothered me for a week that I can't find the right solution over Internet.I've tried to add the parameters which my camera may need.But it appear the same problem.
If you have time, can you try to help me？Or can you guide me where the problem may arise.I will be very grateful for your help.I look forward to your reply.

Actually,my final target is to use dshow cammand to display my camera and push the stream using SRT at the same time.So that I can pull the SRT stream at another computer to compare two screen and then get the delay Intuitively and visually.I've built SRT(32bit) and ffmpeg(32bit v4.1.1) successfully,but my dshow command seems like that it doesn't work well.

Comment: Dshow has been under work recently incl. critical bug fixes, so I'd try the latest nightly to see if your problem goes away

Comment: My English is not very good, so could you please speak to me in a more simple way? But anyway I am grateful to you.(qwq)

Comment: FFmpeg dshow has evolved a lot since v4.4.1. So, try the latest master build first to see if your issue has been addressed already

Comment: thanks a lot.I've got it through ffmpeg(v5.0).^-^Question solved.